# Accept message from gsm devices and update table periodically

Tags: php, sms, gsm

A gsm device sends data in each 3 seconds. 100 such devices are sending messages and there is a device to accept these messages. I want to insert these messages in mysql table in each 5 minutes using php.

Comment: Are the GSM devices sending SMSs? What device is receiving the messages? You want to insert the messages into what? At a guess, I'd say you have some devices sending SMSs and you have a modem to receive the messages. You want to put the messages into a database, but only keeping 1 message per sender for every 5 minute interval. Is this correct?

Comment: @ptomli    Yes, GSM devices are sending sms. I want to insert it into mysql table and keep all messages from each user, not one message per sender.

Comment: What stops you from inserting the messages into the db table? Just do it...

Comment: I have to make sure that data loss is not happening.

Comment: Where do you expect data loss? I am missing the question in your question...

Comment: Please try to explain how you are receiving these messages. Is the receiving system connected to a GSM modem, or are you using an aggregator (like BulkSMS)? You are not indicating how you differentiate a 'user' from a 'sender'. Try rephrasing your question to include much more detail, it's simply not possible to suggest an answer with the details you have provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [cronjob](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) to execute each 5 minutes a php script that will introduce the date in your db. Php scripts are executed in the webserver without persistence and this is not a php job to execute itself at some intervals. Some things can be done in PHP and for others are other tools available.

Alternatively you could use javascript and setTimeout function to call for a php script but Js is client executed and is not reliable enough for what you want.